# White Balance/Auto Focus in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to control white balance/exposure/auto focus in custom camera? Not find a proper solution yet.
Am working on Camera Controller class but it not works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following package `adv_camera` from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/adv_camera), package [link](https://pub.dev/packages/adv_camera). but it only support focus for now

Comment: I used this adv_camera package but it support only focus. But i need to control white balance in custom camera